# Rectangles instead of whitespace in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, typeface

A website I'm working on is using a custom embedded font that newer versions of Chrome on Windows don't seem to like. Instead of whitespace, weird white rectangles show up. Removing the custom typeface fixes the problem but that's hardly an acceptable solution.

Screenshot: [image: Chrome messing up whitespace]

Does anyone know how Chrome interprets whitespace so that I can fix the typeface?

Comment: Instead of a normal whitespace you can use `&nbsp;` but even better set a left/right margin for your menu items and get rid of all the spaces

Comment: Is your text inside an <li> by any chance? Can you show us your markup?

Comment: link: http://danielmaly.net/zdhenik/ &nbsp produces the same result and the menu already has margins

Comment: @DanielMaly Get rid of that space then, use instead `margin-left: 5px` or whatever you need. And you can also target the last `<a>` to not show that margin using `a:last-child {}`

Comment: @Caelea The menu is not the issue, the text inside a <p> is. There are zero spaces in the nav bar.

Comment: @DanielMaly The only thing that comes in my mind is to try to generate the font again for Chrome using http://www.fontsquirrel.com/, becuase teh FF version is ok

Comment: Have you tried with other webfonts? Seems like some characters in the html-code are displayed wrong.
You could try Optima at http://www.fonts.com/web-fonts. They have a free plan also.

Comment: I had a similar problem and found that I was feeding font squirrel a font that didn't include the glyph that was needed, so the result also didn't include that glyph, even checking fix missing glyphs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the typeface didn't define the Unicode whitespace character (0020). All the other browsers substituted the missing character for whitespace, except Chrome. Fixed by editing the font and adding the character.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the CSS propety `letter-spacing` to something other that the default value (`normal`) may produce this behaviour.