# Chrome wrapping text when using multiple languages and web fonts on windows

Tags: css, google-chrome, fonts, whitespace

I have a site that has content in Arabic and English, I'm using a web font for styling the headers and some buttons [Source Sans Pro](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/source-sans-pro) for English and [Droid Arabic Kufi](http://openfontlibrary.org/en/font/droid-arabic-kufi) for Arabic, so basically my css would look like this:

```
.header {
    font-family: 'Droid Arabic Kufi', 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}
```

The problem happens in Chrome on Windows when the element has a `float` style or is displayed as an `inline-block`, it for some reason wraps the text even it's not necessary, here is an example:

This is the sample on Mac, it shows on one line, with 156px width.

[image: Mac]

This is the sample on Windows, it shows on two lines with 154px width.

[image]

If I add `white-space: nowrap;` to the element windows will show it right, and what really makes it weird is that it uses the same width 154px.

[image]

I don't want to apply `white-space: nowrap;` because sometimes I need to wrap the text, and it's not an easy job to look for places where we need to use the custom font and not wrap the text.

I think the problem has something to do with white spaces, especially because I faced an issue that sometimes [whitespace is replaced by a rectangle on Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12914256/rectangles-instead-of-whitespace-in-chrome)

This issue only shows in Chrome on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar problem, and using `white-space: nowrap;` is not an option.

We just have to wait for a chrome update, as I tested the same page in [chrome beta channel v32](http://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel) and no unnecessary wrapping was performed.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with various Google Web fonts in Chrome.

I added a space to the end of the printed text and chrome was able to resolve the length and wrapping properly.

*My 2c on why this works*

*My guess is there is some extra step in rendering web-fonts and executes after the css-preprocessor has worked out the font spacing. Adding the extra space acts as a buffer for the css preprocessor.*

Comment: It didn't solve it for me, still looking for a better solution.